# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x \to 8} \frac{x^{2/3}-4}{x^{1/3}-2}$ without L'Hospital

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

The problem $$\lim\limits_{x \to 8} \frac{x^{2/3}-4}{x^{1/3}-2}$$ is on my problem set due tomorrow.

In class, we only addressed limits with square roots, and we would just multiply by a conjugate to solve the limit. However, here multiplying by $$\left(\frac{x^{1/3}+2}{x^{1/3}+2}\right)^2$$  only produces another fraction where the denominator is zero when x=8. We have not yet learned L'Hospital's or derivatives in general so that is not an option. Is there perhaps some way to use limit squeeze theorem on this problem, or am I forgetting about some really easy limit law that solves this problem

Comment: Do you know what $\dfrac{a^2-4}{a-2}$ is?

Comment: Since the numerator factors easily (as a few others have already hinted here) it's not a particularly efficient method for this problem but for a cube-root expression, the analogue of multiplying by the conjugate to rationalize a denominator is to use $(u - a)(u^2 + a u + a^2) = u^3 - a^3$. (In this case, take $u = x^{1 / 3}$.)

Answer (score 5):

You can sub $u=x^{1/3}$ then you have 
$$
\frac{u^2-4}{u-2}
$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 8} \frac{x^{2/3}-4}{x^{1/3}-2}=\lim\limits_{x\to8}(x^{1/3}+2)$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Numerator:

$x^{2/3}-4=(x^{1/3})^2-2^2=$

$(x^{1/3}-2)(x^{1/3}+2)$;

Denominator:

$x^{1/3}-2$.

Now consider $\lim x^{1/3} \rightarrow 2$.

Used: $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$.